# Undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.fn.gridPaging.flip')

Tags: vb.net, phantomjs

I am accessing a webpage in my VB.net code using PhantomJS. The webpage loads the data through Ajax call and displays it in some Javascript Grid. The data on the first page is loaded successfully. Now to move to next page paging is present which again loads the data through Ajax call. So far I have managed to write this code.

```
             Try
                Dim jsContent As String = "var system = require('system');" &
                                         "var page = require('webpage').create();" &
                                         "page.open('" + strLinkHanoi + "', function() {" &
                                            "page.evaluate(function(){" &
                                                "$.fn.gridPaging.flip('DbGridPager_1',2,523);" &
                                            "});" &
                                         "system.stdout.writeLine(page.content);" &
                                         "phantom.exit();" &
                                         "});"

                pmJS.RunScript(jsContent, Nothing, Nothing, ms)
            Finally
                ' ensure that phantomjs.exe is stopped
                pmJS.Abort()
            End Try
```

The page html code looks like this,

```
<a title="Go to 2" onclick="$.fn.gridPaging.flip('DbGridPager_1',2,523);" href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>

<a title="Go to 3" onclick="$.fn.gridPaging.flip('DbGridPager_1',3,523);" href="javascript:void(0)">3</a>
```

As it can be seen in the code above that I am calling $.fn.gridPaging.flip in the page.evaluate to go to the next page but when I execute it, it gives me following error,

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.fn.gridPaging.flip')
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
```

How this can be achieved?

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ Artjom B. It gives me the website source so it completes successfully but on the top of the page content it says  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.fn.gridPaging.flip')

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1

Comment: Yes, I can see that. The error suggests that the JavaScript resource where the functionality is defined wasn't received/executed. A way to make sure is by listening to the events I suggested. Have you done that? Did anything new appear?